# How to get multilevel data in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new in django framework.I have 4 tables in mysql database. I want to fetch data from main table with translation table and city table with its translation. 
My model.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    #id             = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    iso_code    = models.CharField(max_length=2, unique=True)
    slug        = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_featured = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rh_countries'

class CountryTranslation(models.Model):
    country     = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    locale      = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rh_countries_translations'

class City(models.Model):
    country     = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rh_cities'

class CityTranslation(models.Model):
    city        = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    locale      = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rh_city_translations'
```

And This is my views.py

```
Country.objects.filter(
                            is_featured=1,
                            countrytranslation__locale='en'
                        ).annotate(
                            name=F('countrytranslation__name')
                            totalCities=Count('city', distinct=True)
                        )
```

I want to fetch all cities from city table which has foreign key country_id and city name from city translation lable.

Comment: Are you sure that the query conditons are `foreign key country_id ` ***AND*** `city name `?